Closed formula for $1^3+4^3+7^3+\dots+(3n-2)^3$?
$$a_n=\frac{1^{3}+4^{3}+7^{3}+.....+(3n-2)^{3}}{(1+4+7+....+(3n-2))^{2}}$$
I know how to express the denominator but what about the numerator?
Is there a formula?
I was thinking of multiplying the numerator 3 times but I don't know if it's correct!

It is not clear what you mean by "multiplying the numerator 3 times".

Please take a [tour] on what counts as a good question--context and effort. I'm not seeing much of either here.

the numerator  sequence is $1, 65, 408, 1408, 3605, 7701, ...$ There are rational coefficients $p,q,r,s, t$   where your sequence is $pn^4 + q n^3 + r n^2 + s n + t$   Writing out the equations for $n = 1,2,3,4,5$ and the first five values above leads to a linear system of equations for $p,q,r,s,t.$  The denominators happen, in this method, because you are inverting a 5 by 5 matrix of integers.  Example for $n=1$  the row is $p+q+r+s+t = 1.$  For $n=2$  it is $16p+8q+4r+2s+t = 65.$

that worked....

Hint : The numerator is $$\sum_{k=1}^n (3k-2)^3$$ Break the cube, expand, and sum.
Here's another hint by popular demand : \begin{align*}\sum_{k=1}^n (3k-2)^3&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(27k^3-54k^2+36k-8\right)\\&=27\sum_{k=1}^nk^3-54\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+36\sum_{k=1}^nk-8\sum_{k=1}^n1\end{align*}

This needs more detail than this.

@Mike Fair point. That is why I did not solve the question, just gave a small push.

As this is an "answer" you actually need to present the crux of a solution though.

I think this is almost enough to contruct a solution. If the OP wants more elaboration, I shall be happy to provide.

Would the downvoter care to explain?

I was not the downvoter--I would say if I were--but that this answer is so sparse, does indeed justify the downvote as far as I see it. This answer as I said before really needs elaboration. Keep in mind that the answer is not just for the person who asked the question but also for whoever else may visit afterwards.

This should help even more:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac16n(n+1)(2n+1)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^3=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2$$
